# Find column number that satisfies condition based on another vector

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, threshold

I'm trying to train a classifier for the classes "Hit", "Miss" based on the variables `User`, `Planning Horizon`, `Material`, and some more.
Most of them are categorical variables except for `Planning Horizon` (integer)

I have unbalanced data so im trying to use thresholding to select the final output of the model (Rather than just using the default 0.5 probability)

The variable `User` has the most impact on the class outcome, so im trying to use different thresholds for every user. Im thinking about using the naive bayes posterior probability P(Class|User).

The question is, how can i apply those different rules for the output matrix of the model:

The "Thresholds matrix", a different threshold for every user:

```
User    P("Hit"|User)
A           0.80
B           0.40
C           0.61
```

And the outputs of the classifier (P(Hit) and P(Miss)) and the last column (Final Prediction) is what i need to construct.

```
User    P("Miss")   P("Hit")    Final Prediction
B           0.79    0.21        Miss
B           0.20    0.80        Hit
A           0.15    0.85        Hit
C           0.22    0.78        Hit
A           0.90    0.10        Miss
B           0.80    0.20        Miss
```

Notice the first row gets a MISS because P(Miss) is lower than P(Hit|User=B)

Comment: What about merging your Threshold Matrix to the results create the Final Prediction again by comparing the `P("Hit")` with your `P("Hit"|User)`?

Comment: **1.** provide data to work with e.g. `dput(head(yourData,20))` **2.** Show and mark your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I would merge my threshold matrix and then create the `Final Prediction` column by hand like this.

```
df <- read.table(text='User P("Miss") P("Hit") "Final Prediction"
B 0.79 0.21 Miss
B 0.20 0.80 Hit
A 0.15 0.85 Hit
C 0.22 0.78 Hit
A 0.90 0.10 Miss
B 0.80 0.20 Miss', 
                 header=TRUE, sep=' ', check.names=FALSE)

thm <- read.table(text='User P("Hit"|User)
A 0.80
B 0.40
C 0.61', 
                  header=TRUE, sep=' ', check.names=FALSE)

thmdf <- merge(thm, df)

thmdf['My Final Prediction'] <- 
  ifelse(thmdf$`P(Hit)` < thmdf$`P(Hit|User)`, 
         'Miss',
         'Hit')

thmdf
```